# Load svg dinamically as a react component

Tags: reactjs, svg

My app should render about 30000 svg elements, depending on routes.
If route is like www.myapp.com/svg-data/person it should render person.svg.

Later on (same route), this svg could be modified: add background color, some text, or some predefined layers.
I guess I should load the svg as a react component. I'm having a look at library https://github.com/boopathi/react-svg-loader but I don't think it really fit my purpose.

My last thought is about fetching svg data as string and render it inside a component which returns an svg among other things...

I should build a generic component, that renders whatever svg that comes as a parameter:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.params.searchText) {
      this.props.requestSVG(this.props.params.searchText)
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.params.searchText !== nextProps.params.searchText) {
      this.props.requestSVG(nextProps.params.searchText)
    }
  }
```

This component would render something like:

```
render() {
   const {svgData, textForSVGData} = this.props
   let svgText=null

   if (textForSVGData) {
     svgText= <text x='250' y='150' font-size='55'> {textForSVGData} </text>
   }

   return (
      <svg>
        {this.props.svgData}
        {svgText}
      </svg>
   )

}
```

Depending on props it should add text, or any other things on demand. Do I miss something? This is the good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, a couple of things:

- Create each SVG in a single component, this will help you to isolate your SVG's behavior, styles, props and so on
- Use [higher order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) to create the generic component, and use it as a proxy to pass dynamics props to your SVG components and add common SVG behavior if needed
- Regarding the routers, you can have a mapper Router - Icon or directly set the SVG component as the router component to render

The main goal of the `SvgRendering` is to act as a higher order component and render the given component with the given props.

```
class SvgRenderer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { invert: true };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ inverted: !this.state.inverted });
  }

  render() {
    const { Svg, svgProps } = this.props;
    const { inverted } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle inverted svg</button>
        <div><Svg {...svgProps} inverted={inverted}/></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Meanwhile `PlayIcon` (the SVG) aims setting custom styles, text, shapes, etc.

```
const PlayIcon = (props) => {
  const { className, inverted } = props;
  const classes = className ? ['icon', 'logo', 'className'] : ['icon', 'logo'];

  if (inverted) classes.push('inverted');

  return (
    <div className={classes.join(' ')}>
      <svg
        version="1.1"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path d="M256.000,512.000 C114.615,512.000 0.000,397.385 0.000,256.000 C0.000,114.615 114.615,0.000 256.000,0.000 C397.385,0.000 512.000,114.615 512.000,256.000 C512.000,397.385 397.385,512.000 256.000,512.000 ZM151.172,128.000 L151.172,384.000 L406.907,256.000 L151.172,128.000 Z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm being very generic with this suggestion and as result of these recommendations I have created and example of implementation in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82451/

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I'm using webpack. Just don't know how to integrate 30000 thousands of svg components into my js code!